# Solve the equation $(tan θ − 2)(9 sin^2 θ − 1) = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the given equation. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. Let $k$ be any integer. Round terms to three decimal places where appropriate. If there is no solution, enter NO SOLUTION.)

$$(\tan \theta − 2)(9 \sin^2 \theta − 1) = 0$$

So if I set both equal to zero and solve I get

$$\theta=\tan^{-1}(2)$$

$$\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac13\right)$$

$$\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(-\frac13\right)$$

What do I do next?

Update:

There should be five answers, so far I have 4:

$1.107+\pi k$ which came from the tangent

$0.340+2\pi k$ which came from arcsin (1/3)

$2.802+2\pi k$ which came from arcsin (1/3)

$5.943+2\pi k$ which came from arcsin (-1/3)

There should be one more from came from arcsin (-1/3) but I don't know what to add/subtract from arcsin (-1/3) to get it.

Edit: I got the last one it was $3.481+2\pi k$

Comment: $9\sin^2 \theta-1=0$ gives $\sin \theta=\pm \frac13$ so there are in fact 3 solutions.

Comment: The sine is $\pm \frac{1}{3}$. The domain of the trig functions has not been specified, so there are infinitely many answers, tough to do a comma-separated list.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit of a novice
I get θ=tan−1(2) but not θ=sin−1(1/9)

Comment: what exactly is k?

Comment: @pMarkov k is any integer, so you usually add it to the end of the result like $+2\pi k$ or $+\pi k$ so that you include all answers since there are infinite answers

Comment: I need help finding the sin inverse of -1/3. hold on let me edit my post

Answer (score 1):

A Couple things:

You should get 3 results:
$ (\tanθ−2)(9\sin2θ−1)=0 \Rightarrow$

$ (1) \tanθ =2$

$ (2) \sinθ = \frac{1}{3}$

$ (3) \sinθ = -\frac{1}{3} $

From here, you would use the inverse functions as you did- however, it seems as if you may use a calculator to get your results, which would probably be your best bet (assuming you are given a fixed domain)

Comment: If the question asks for values of k for constants it probably wants the answer in the form (for example) θ = π/3 + kπ/2, π/19 + 2kπ etc. thus giving all the possible answers since the domain is not specified. This is not the actual answer - I don't have a calculator...

Comment: So for example $1.107+\pi k$ is the answer for tangent.

Comment: my mistake- i presumed since you wanted it in decimal form you only wanted one solution: in general, your other answers would be -.340 + 2 Pi (k)     and .340 + 2 Pi (k)    (assuming you don't want these combined)

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(\tan \theta-2)(9\sin^2\theta-1)=0$$ Now, writing the general solutions for $\theta$ $$\implies \tan \theta-2=0 \iff \tan\theta=2\iff \color{}{\theta =k\pi+\tan^{-1}(2)} \iff \color{blue}{\theta =k\pi+1.107}$$ $$\implies 9\sin^2\theta-1=0 \iff \sin^2\theta=\frac{1}{9}\iff \color{}{\theta=k\pi\pm\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)} \iff \color{blue}{\theta=k\pi\pm0.41} $$ 
Where, k is any integer.